# Swift Package Manager - Custom Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am new to the Swift Package Manager so bear with me. I have searched around and haven't found an answer to my current problem. I am creating a custom framework. When I create a CocoaTouch Framework and then build it, I am able to find the ProjectName.framework in my "Products" folder in the project directory. However, when I use SPM to add a dependency (Alamofire for example) and generate a new project file with the

swift package generate-xcodeproj

terminal command, the Alamofire.framework shows up in "Products" but the ProjectName.framework is no longer available. Instead there is a ProjectName executable file. I am no longer able to find the framework or even include the whole project in another as a dependency.

[image]

In the image above, I expect to see KonvurjKit.framework in "Products" but I no longer see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your project contains `main.swift`, Swift Package Manager produces an executable. You should add your framework files, other than `main.swift` and then run `swift package generate-xcodeproj`. A framework will be generated in `Products` in the generated Xcode project.

If you want to create both an executable and a library (framework), a possible `Source` layout is this:

`Sources
   - KonvurjKitExecutable
     main.swift
   - KonvurjKit
     <your framework files here>`

Add two targets to your `Package.swift`:

`targets: [
     Target(name: "KonvurjKitExecutable", 
            dependencies: [.Target(name: "KonvurjKit")]),
     Target(name: "KonvurjKit")]`

If you want to create a library (framework) only, just remove `main.swift` and add your framework files directly to `Sources`.

Comment: Thanks! I kept getting errors about the layout but I eventually realized that if I ran "swift package init" instead of "swift package init --type executable" the project set itself up nicely. Your answer helped me get there though.